# Call a function conditionally

Tags: html, vbscript

I have a Sub in my VBScript application. It populates a table on the page on clicking a search button, there is another button that clears the page using the `window.location.reload()` method.

My issue is when a user clicks the search button it populates a table, then the user can click the search button again and the table will be appended with more data.

I want that first the page should be cleared and then the table should be populated.
There are iterations, so I can't simply call `window.location.reload()` within the `Search(directory)` Sub.

```html
<p>
<input name="Clear" type="button" class = "button" value="Clear" OnClick="window.location.reload()">
<input name="Search" type="button" class = "buttongo aright" value="Search" OnClick="Search"> 
</p>
```

My VBScript code is:

```
Sub Search(directory)
    Dim flag
    Dim found
    Dim nodeinfo(4)
    Dim ipath
    On Error Resume Next
    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)
    Set Fls = fldr.Files
    For Each item In Fls
        sFSpec = FSO.GetAbsolutePathName(item)
        If LCase(FSO.GetExtensionName(item.Name)) = "xml" Then
            objMSXML.async = True
            '...
            'More code here to generate table mytable ...
            '...
        End If
    Next
    Set fldrs = fldr.SubFolders
    For Each item In fldrs
        Search item.path
    Next
End Sub
```

Currently I am disabling the search button if there is data in the table:

```vb
If no_of_occurence > 0 Then document.getElementById("search_btn").disabled = True
```

**Edit**

To generate table:

```vb
Set mytable = document.createElement("table")
mytable.setAttribute "id", "mytable"
mytable.setAttribute "align", "center" 
Set thead = document.createElement("thead")
Set tr = document.createElement("tr")
Set th = document.createElement("th")

th.setAttribute "colSpan","5" 
thead.appendChild tr
Set tr2 = document.createElement("tr")
Set th1 = document.createElement("th")  
Set th2 = document.createElement("th")
Set th3 = document.createElement("th")
Set th4 = document.createElement("th")
Set th5 = document.createElement("th")
th1.innerText = "ABC"
th2.innerText = "DEF"
th3.innerText = "GHI"
th4.innerText = "JKL"
th5.innerText = "MNO"
tr2.appendChild th1
tr2.appendChild th2
tr2.appendChild th3
tr2.appendChild th4
tr2.appendChild th5
thead.appendChild tr2
mytable.appendChild thead

Set td1 = document.createElement("td")
td1.innerText = nodeinfo(0)
tr3.appendChild td1
```

There is a variable, say `no_of_results`, that holds a number if results are returned. Based on that variable I am disabling the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `<table>` (and `<thead>`) only if they don't exist already:

```vb
Set mytable = document.getElementById("mytable")
If mytable Is Nothing Then
    Set mytable = document.createElement("table")
    '...
    Set thead = document.createElement("thead")
    '...
    mytable.appendChild thead
End If
```

And put the table content into a `<tbody>`, so you can remove existing search results before appending new ones:

```vb
For Each tbody In mytable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
    mytable.removeChild(tbody)
Next

Set tbody = document.createElement("tbody")
'...
'create rows and cells and append them to the table body
'...

mytable.appendChild tbody
```

Answer (score 1):

I had also same problem like this, but in my case i used Javascript and differently handled this situation. In this case try with another function which will call both clear and load functions.

Try this code, call 2 functions on single button click

```
<input name="Search" type="button" class = "buttongo aright" value="Search" OnClick="window.location.reload(); Search();">
```

Comment: <input name="Search" type="button" class = "btn_search align_r" value="Search" OnClick="window.location.reload(); Search();" id="search_btn"> 

Problem calling both function checking...